I would like to conduct performance testing of Azure Event Hubs and Event Grid using Jmeter
I would like to conduct performance testing of Azure's Event Hubs and Event Grid using Jmeter.
First, I downloaded the Event Hubs sampler plugin and configured it as follows.
I configured it with Test Plan > Thread Group > Azure Event Hubs Sampler and succeeded by simply testing whether the setting input values were correct.
The problem is that I need to send more than 30,000 messages per minute to Azure Event Hubs and have them confirmed in Azure.
How should I configure the settings in this case? Regardless of whether I used a loop controller or registered multiple samplers, I could only receive up to 700 messages in about 1 minute. (In the Thread group, I tried changing the user count to 15, 20, 25, 50, and setting the time to 1800 seconds, but they were all the same. .)
I am a first-time user of Jmeter, so I do not have much understanding of this solution. We look forward to hearing valuable answers from experts.
thank you
Change user and time in Thread group.
Registering multiple samplers.
Deploy and use Loop controller
I couldn't use external plugins because I didn't know how to use them.


JMeter's default configuration might not be suitable for high loads:

Make sure that you follow JMeter Best Practices
Make sure to run your tests in command-line non-GUI mode


If this is not enough  and you cannot conduct the required load using a single machine due to lack of CPU/RAM/whatever there is possibility to run JMeter in clustered mode when several load generator machines are running the same test at the same time. See How to Perform Distributed Testing in JMeter article for more details.


